Connecting ElasticSearch Service in Kubernetes env is throwing TLS error
I am currently working on deploying Elasticsearch in a Kubernetes environment using a Helm chart. The pods are being created and are running without issues. However, I am encountering a problem connecting to the Elasticsearch service from a different Python service. The connection attempt results in the following error:
elastic_transport.TlsError: TLS error caused by: TlsError(TLS error caused by: SSLError([SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1006)))

my chart looks like
- name: elasticsearch
  version: 8.5.1
  repository: https://helm.elastic.co

pods seems to be running fine
elasticsearch-master-0                          2/2     Running     0             92m
elasticsearch-master-1                          2/2     Running     0             92m
elasticsearch-master-2                          2/2     Running     0             92m

able to curl the URL by bypassing the verification
curl -k -u elastic https://elasticsearch-master-headless:9200
Enter host password for user 'elastic':
{
  "name" : "elasticsearch-master-2",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "id",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "8.5.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "c1310c45fc534583afe2c1c03046491efba2bba2",
    "build_date" : "2022-11-09T21:02:20.169855900Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "9.4.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.17.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

within the same pod.
but getting
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to elasticsearch-master-headless:9200 

error from different pod in the same cluster.
Any help would be appreciated, please ask for more details if needed.

Are you call the elastic service from your python without using certs ie.) same as -k option from curl bypassing the verification

yes, verify_certs as false.

Thing is even curl is throwing the error with option of -k, from different pod.

Probably try disabling the ssl for elastic search as described here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-tls-certificates.html#k8s-disable-tls

I have tried this as well.

what is the command curl command you are using from other pods?
